# Scheme procedure exception about: incorrect number of arguments

Tags: scheme, chez-scheme

I am a new schemer. Maybe this question is so easy. But it really bothers me.

I defined a procedure

```
(define insertL
    (lambda (new old lat)
      (cond
        ((null? lat) '())
        ((eq? old (car lat)) (cons new lat))
        (else (cons (car lat) (insertL (cdr lat)))))))
```

then I call it

```
> (insertL 2 3 '(1 2 3))
```

Exception occurred

```
Exception: incorrect number of arguments to #<procedure insertL>
```

Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How many arguments does `insertL` take? Are you calling it with the right number of arguments in both places that you call it?

Comment: Thank you. The second call was missing an argument. Actually I just checked where the first call.
I wrote this code in vscode, can't do the syntax check before execution, is there a better editor or IDE?

Comment: @TimChan The syntax is correct - if it weren't, your interpreter would have rejected the code without executing it. The issue is semantics.